# Disabled JavaScript notice, AFTER user signup?

Tags: notification, signup-signon, javascript, warnings

My site relies heavily on JavaScript, and the site is based on user signup

If a user is logged in and has javascript disabled, it throws a notice and disables all major site functions

The question is, when a new user signs up, should I show a javascript-disabled notice at that point, or just let the person sign up and *then* show the notice after he/she logs in?

If I let users without javascript signup, that barrier is removed and probably more users will signup. Then I will gently advice users how to enable javascript, if needed

Would that be ok?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You answered your own question! :)

I think you should allow users to sign up without JavaScript. Users want an easy experience, they don't want to follow steps like how to enable JavaScript - they just want to sign up, do want they need to do and they're done. It's simply too much work to enable JavaScript.

So I think the solution you gave in your answer is perfect.

Comment: Except they won't be able to use the site after they've signed up. This would just delay the realization that they won't be able to do what they need to do.

Comment: @JohnKugelman Correct, but they may accept the fact that they need to enable JavaScript after succeeding in one part.

Comment: I have decided to require JavaScript from the start (need JS for extra bot-block too). Then I put a small notice at signup form if no JS, and all other places a bigger overlay notice.